# The specified channel could not be found EventViewer

Tags: windows, event-viewer, get-eventlog

I am opening windows event viewer security logs which under Windows Logs but its displaying an error as below.(Other logs are working)

> Event viewer cannot open the event log or custom view, Verify that
>   Event Log service is running or query is too long. The specified
>   channel could not be found. Check channel configuration ( 15007)

I tried to create custom view but when Security logs selected it shows the same error message

Btw. i was working with c# EventLogReader class for read Security logs and problem is occured after system restarted.

p.s

Event log service is running, query is not long and Security.evtx is exist at folder and local group policy configs are restored default